# Pandas data frame - lambda calculus and minimum value per series

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a csv that contains 3 columns, count_id, AMV and time.

I am using pandas and have read this in as a data frame.

```
results= pd.read_csv('./output.csv')
```

First, I am sorting the data frame first for count_id and then for AMV.

```
results_sorted = results.sort_index(by=['count_id','AMV'], ascending=[True, True])
```

This gives

```
   count_id   AMV  Hour
0    16012E  4004    14
1    16012E  4026    12
2    16012E  4099    15
3    16012E  4167    11
4    16012E  4239    10
5    16012E  4324    13
6    16012E  4941    16
7    16012E  5088    17
8    16012E  5283     9
9    16012E  5620     8
10   16012E  5946    18
11   16012E  6146     7
12   16012W  3622    10
13   16012W  3904    12
14   16012W  3979    11
15   16012W  4076     9
16   16012W  4189    13
17   16012W  4870    14
18   16012W  4899    18
19   16012W  5107    15
20   16012W  5659     8
21   16012W  6325     7
22   16012W  6460    17
23   16012W  6500    16
```

I now want to perform some normalisation on the data so that I can ultimately plot it on the same plot. What I wish to do is find the minimum value for AMV per series (count_id) and then subtract this minimum value from the given AMV. This will give me a new column AMV_norm.

Which would look like:

```
   count_id   AMV  Hour  AMV_norm
0    16012E  4004    14         0
1    16012E  4026    12        22
2    16012E  4099    15        95
3    16012E  4167    11       163
4    16012E  4239    10       235
5    16012E  4324    13       320
6    16012E  4941    16       937
7    16012E  5088    17      1084
8    16012E  5283     9      1279
9    16012E  5620     8      1616
10   16012E  5946    18      1942
11   16012E  6146     7      2142
12   16012W  3622    10         0
13   16012W  3904    12       282
14   16012W  3979    11       357
15   16012W  4076     9       454
16   16012W  4189    13       567
17   16012W  4870    14      1248
18   16012W  4899    18      1277
19   16012W  5107    15      1485
20   16012W  5659     8      2037
21   16012W  6325     7      2703
22   16012W  6460    17      2838
23   16012W  6500    16      2878
```

How do I define the function that finds the minimum AMV value per series and not the minimum value of AMV overall? It would look something like this:

```
def minimum_series_value(AMV):
    return AMV.argmin()
```

I would then need to create a new column and using a lambda function populate that row. I know it would look something like this:

```
results_sorted['AMV_norm'] = results_sorted.apply(lambda row:results_sorted(row['AMV']))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract the AMV column from the transform min:

```
In [11]: df.groupby('count_id')["AMV"].transform('min')
Out[11]:
0     4004
1     4004
2     4004
3     4004
4     4004
...
21    3622
22    3622
23    3622
dtype: int64

In [12]: df["AMV"] - df.groupby('count_id')["AMV"].transform('min')
Out[12]:
0        0
1       22
2       95
3      163
4      235
...
21    2703
22    2838
23    2878
dtype: int64

In [13]: df["AMV_norm"] = df["AMV"] - df.groupby('count_id')["AMV"].transform('min')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to group on `count_id`, and then calculate the difference between the current values and the minimum value for that group.

```
df['AMV_norm'] = (df.groupby('count_id').AMV
                    .transform(lambda group_series: group_series - np.min(group_series)))

>>> df
   count_id   AMV  Hour  AMV_norm
0    16012E  4004    14         0
1    16012E  4026    12        22
2    16012E  4099    15        95
3    16012E  4167    11       163
4    16012E  4239    10       235
5    16012E  4324    13       320
6    16012E  4941    16       937
7    16012E  5088    17      1084
8    16012E  5283     9      1279
9    16012E  5620     8      1616
10   16012E  5946    18      1942
11   16012E  6146     7      2142
12   16012W  3622    10         0
13   16012W  3904    12       282
14   16012W  3979    11       357
15   16012W  4076     9       454
16   16012W  4189    13       567
17   16012W  4870    14      1248
18   16012W  4899    18      1277
19   16012W  5107    15      1485
20   16012W  5659     8      2037
21   16012W  6325     7      2703
22   16012W  6460    17      2838
23   16012W  6500    16      2878
```

**EDIT**:
The approach by @AndyHayden is slightly faster:

```
%timeit df["AMV"] - df.groupby('count_id')["AMV"].transform('min')
1000 loops, best of 3: 736 µs per loop

%timeit df.groupby('count_id').AMV.transform(lambda x: x - np.min(x))
1000 loops, best of 3: 804 µs per loop

%timeit df.groupby('count_id').AMV.apply(lambda x: x - np.min(x))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 ms per loop
```

Comment: It seems strange to use a lambda that returns a Series in a transform! (Rather than use an apply.)

Comment: I guess they use the same path, *but* tranform usually means that one value is spread on the group (e.g. transform('min')) whereas apply means that the group can return anything. But y'know I'm not sure, that was my understanding.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I am more comfortable with using lambda but as you say Andy's response is faster. Thanks for the effort!